# Regex replace colon prefix in comma separated list except quoted

Tags: regex

I'd like to have a Regexp that replaces colons (`:`) in with question marks (`?`), as shown below.
But it should *preserve* colons if they're inside *single quotes* (`'`).

For example, this input string:

```
(:a,:abc,'quoted with :colon, and comma',:more)
```

Should be changed to:

```
(?a,?abc,'quoted with :colon, and comma',?more)
```

Comment: What is the BNF grammar of the text? I can write a regex that works for this case, but not guarantee for other cases.

Comment: `@user2001158` **Welcome to StackOverflow!** I've edited your question to help others understand your problem better. Update it if it's not correct.

Comment: @Wiseguy My mistake. Comment removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another solution that works with `replaceAll`.

Raw regex:

```
((?:^\(|\G)(?: *'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*' *,| *[^:' ][^,]* *,)* *):([^,]* *(?:,|\)$))
```

Quoted string (used in `replaceAll`):

```
"((?:^\\(|\\G)(?: *'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*' *,| *[^:' ][^,]* *,)* *):([^,]* *(?:,|\\)$))"
```

Replacement (used in `replaceAll`):

```
"$1?$2"
```

Sample input:

```
(  :a  ,  :abc,  'quoted with :colon, and comma', skdhfks'sdfkdf  , :sdf, 'sdfds\'f', :sdfksdf, sdkhfksd , :dfsd,  sdfk'fjsdhfkf, 'werwer', :sdf, :Sdf, skhfskjdf, 'asdads\' :asdkahsd ad'   )
```

Sample output:

```
(  ?a  ,  ?abc,  'quoted with :colon, and comma', skdhfks'sdfkdf  , ?sdf, 'sdfds\'f', ?sdfksdf, sdkhfksd , ?dfsd,  sdfk'fjsdhfkf, 'werwer', ?sdf, ?Sdf, skhfskjdf, 'asdads\' :asdkahsd ad'   )
```

Basically, spaces before and after `,` are freely allowed. If `'` is not the first character then it is not considered quoted string. `'` is allowed to be escaped inside quoted string - actually any sort of escaping with `\` is allowed. Empty argument is not allowed, e.g. `(:a, , :b)`.

[**DEMO**](http://www.regex101.com/r/kR5kB3)

Without a detailed specification of your text, I will just make some wild assumptions here as you can see.

**Explanation**

For ease of explanation. I'll remove some capturing groups `()`, which is only useful for the replacement.

```
(?:^\(|\G)(?: *'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*' *,| *[^:' ][^,]* *,)* *:[^,]* *(?:,|\)$)
```

Separate it out (note that some lines have space in front, it is part of the regex):

```
(?:^\(|\G)
(?:
 *'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*' *,
|
 *[^:' ][^,]* *,
)*
 *:[^,]* *
(?:,|\)$)
```

Each match of the regex will contain: tokens that should not be replaced, followed by a single token that needs replacing.

The regex starts off with `(?:^\(|\G)`, which will match `(` at the beginning of the string, or continue from position of last match `\G`.

Tokens that should not be replaces are either quoted string `'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'` or `[^:' ][^,]*` text sequence that doesn't start with `'` or `:`, and doesn't contain comma `,`. I allow escaping in quoted string by using `\\.`, which means `\` followed by any character. I allow any number of uninterested tokens by `*`.

You can see a number of space followed by `*`, which means I allowed arbitrary spacing before and after the token.

Then the token we are interested in: `:[^,]*`.

Then the regex ends with `(?:,|\)$)`, which means it encounters `)` at the end, or a `,`. This ending part is necessary for the `\G` to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "(:a,:abc,'quoted with :colon, and comma',:more)";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
boolean inQuote = false;
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '\'') {
        inQuote = !inQuote;
        sb.append(c);
    } else if (inQuote) {
        sb.append(c);
    } else if(c == ':') {
        sb.append('?');
    } else {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
str = sb.toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

Produces the expected output of `(?a,?abc,'quoted with :colon, and comma',?more)`. However, it obviously is not using regex. Also keep in mind my solution will fail if you allow escaping of quotes.

Comment: +1 Why the downvote? Boris clearly says it knows the author wants RegExps, but this is more robust (especially, if escaping were to be added) and thus a valid and useful answer.

Comment: @jmendeth The downvote is fair enough - my answer in that time was a mix of stupidity and errors

Comment: Oh, then I think leaving a comment to notify them (or edit 'em yourself) is better than just downvoting. :/

Comment: @BorisStrandjev it was me (the downvoter), i was actually leaving to home from office when i downvoted, thought to leave a comment but it started bloody snowing here so i had to rush, anyways+1 for your answer now as it is complete .. cheers :)

Comment: Anyway, it's funny to see the bottom answer climb up to the top. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the `:` that are followed by `even numbers` of `quotes (')`. It would work for this case at least: -

```
String str = "(:a,:abc,'quoted with :colon, and comma',:more)";     
str = str.replaceAll("[:](?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)", "?");

System.out.println(str);
```

**Output: -**

```
(?a,?abc,'quoted with :colon, and comma',?more)
```

So, the `:` inside the `quotes`, will never be followed by an even number of `quotes`, given that you are having a closing quote for every opening quote, and hence it will not be replaced by `?`.